# Is it possible to save flv videos streamed via RTMP?

Tags: flash, http, rtmp

It's easy enough to find the flv file on sites that use http to serve it up, but what about when they use RTMP?

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know there is no straightforward/easy way to accomplish this by yourself. You could try out the [replay media catcher](http://all-streaming-media.com/faq/recording-media-stream/faq-record-download-capture-save-flash-flv-video-rtmp.htm) (althought not free). [Here](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/record-rtmp-flash-video-flv-stream-embedded-t2324.html?s=48ccb5592ef07660cd98197253abcc27&) is a list of softwares similar to replay media catcher.


Edit: I just tried the software [flv recorder](http://www.downloadatoz.com/howto/save-record-capture-flv-video-audio-steaming-through-http-rtmp-protocol.html) and was able to easily download an flv file over rtmp. Just follow the instructions described on the page to install it.

Answer (score 2):

search for *rtmpdump* or *flvstreamer* (the encryption-less more "free" alternative)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions (RTMPDump):
[Videohelp.com](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/311893-How-to-download-flash-video-RTMP-RTMPE-streams-using-free-software)